# How to break / exit out of a For loop in Googlesheets Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How do I break out of a loop / stop a function when a specific logical condition is true in Googlesheets script. In my case, I have a program which, in a loop continuously sets the value of cell B1 and evaluates the result in cell D11.

What I want is that if the result is a string NNN, then the program must stop immediately.

Following is what I have, but the program doesn't exit / stop / quit when the logical condition is true (the program otherwise works fine). Any help appreciated.

---

```
function loopX() {
  var xx;
  var yy;
......
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    sheet.getRange('B1').setValue(data[i][0]);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    Utilities.sleep(4000);
    if (sheet.getRange('D11').getValue() == 'NNN') 

      exit();

  }
......
}
```

#### Updated

```
function loopC() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('SheetN'); // name of your sheet
    var data = ss.getSheetByName('data').getRange('A625:A2910').getValues()‌​;
    if (sheet.getRange('D11').getValue() != "NNN") {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            sheet.getRange('B1').setValue(data[i][0]);
            SpreadsheetApp.flush();
            Utilities.sleep(4000);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use `break` to go out from FOR LOOP. I think that this is a simple way.

#### Sample script :

```
var ar = [["e1"], ["e2"], ["e3"], ["e4"], ["NNN"], ["e6"]];
for (var i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
  if (ar[i][0] == 'NNN') {
      break;
  }
}
Logger.log(i) // 4
```

#### Modified your script :

If this is reflected to your script, it can modify as follows.

```
function loopX() {
  var xx;
  var yy;
......
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    sheet.getRange('B1').setValue(data[i][0]);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    Utilities.sleep(4000);
    if (sheet.getRange('D11').getValue() == 'NNN') {
      break;
    }
  }
......
}
```

But, in your script, I think that `sheet.getRange('D11').getValue()` might be able to be written to out of FOR LOOP like below. About this, since I don't know the detail your script, please confirm it.

```
if (sheet.getRange('D11').getValue() != 'NNN') {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    sheet.getRange('B1').setValue(data[i][0]);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    Utilities.sleep(4000);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I tried both, did't work. The loop kept on going and didn't break / the program didn't stop when for a specific value of i, the value of D11 was NNN. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: @Tapan Samaddar I cannot find your whole script and sheet from your question. I'm sorry. Can I ask you about your script with my sample? If you can do, please import it on your question.

Comment: function loopC() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('SheetN');   // name of your sheet
  var data = ss.getSheetByName('data').getRange('A625:A2910').getValues();
 
  if (sheet.getRange('D11').getValue() != "NNN") {
    
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    sheet.getRange('B1').setValue(data[i][0]);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    Utilities.sleep(4000);
  }
    
 }
  
}

Also the value of Cell D11 is calculated as:
=if(AND(SUM(M214:M216)>2,O216>$G$6,V212<1,V213<1),"NNN","NA")

Comment: @Tapan Samaddar When the for loop is run in your modified script, it means that ``D11`` is not ``NNN``. When you see the ``D11`` on your spreadsheet, is the cell of ``D11`` ``NNN``? If it's so, how about the change from ``if (sheet.getRange('D11').getValue() != "NNN") {`` to ``if (sheet.getRange('D11').getDisplayValue() != "NNN") {``?

Comment: if (sheet.getRange('D11').getDisplayValue() != "NNN") {...} didn't work. Somehow the expression is not being executed.

Comment: @Tapan Samaddar ``sheet.getRange('D11').getDisplayValue()`` works. So ``if (sheet.getRange('D11').getDisplayValue() != "NNN") {...}`` works. Please tell me the error at ``if (sheet.getRange('D11').getDisplayValue() != "NNN") {...}``. And can you show us the sample spreadsheet?